# Scalaz .option - what is this shorthand for?

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-option

I'm seeing the following code:

```
val a  = (x: Int) => (x == 1).option(doSomethingUnrealiable(1))
```

Is this equivalent to:

```
val a  = (x: Int) => if (x == 1) Option(doSomethingUnrealiable(1))
```

I ask because I'm struggling to find doco on Scalaz for this `.option` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this code is equivalent to:

```
<...> if (x == 1) Some(doSomethingUnrealiable(1)) else None
```

Result type of `if (x == 1) Option(...)` is `Any` (just like `if (x == 1) Option(...) else ()`).

See [`Scalaz` documentation](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.std.BooleanFunctions):

> Returns the given argument in `Some` if `cond` is `true`, `None` otherwise.

See also [Scalaz cheat sheet](http://eed3si9n.com/ja/scalaz-cheat-sheet):

```
(1 < 10) option 1 assert_=== 1.some
```

Comment: Thanks - any doco on the ScalaZ .option function apart from reading the library source code?